# How ilike() method internally works in Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate

Can some help in internal works of ilike(), as I gone through hibernate api but  did not get clear. For example I am searching for a name i.e. vijay , and I have entered into search box as VIJAY(in capital) . 
1. How actually it compares both?
2. Does hibernate use any function to convert VIJAY into lower case then it compares?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the database dialect used.

Just checked the code, it comes to this (from [LikeExpression](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/4.3.7.Final/org/hibernate/criterion/LikeExpression.java#LikeExpression))

```
if ( dialect.supportsCaseInsensitiveLike() ) {
    return column +" " + dialect.getCaseInsensitiveLike() + " ?" + escape;
}
else {
    return dialect.getLowercaseFunction() + '(' + column + ')' + " like ?" + escape;
}
```

So, the dialect is responsible for actual SQL expression. For example, on PostgreSQL `getCaseInsensitiveLike()` returns `ilike`, while in Oracle dialect `supportsCaseInsensitiveLike()` returns `false`, so the expression is generated as

```
dialect.getLowercaseFunction() + '(' + column + ')' + " like ?" + escape;
```

which is

```
lower(column) like ?
```